# Javascript / Angular - Function runs too fast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my simple filter table.

```
<tr class="text-center" ng-repeat="ticket in filteredTickets = (vm.tickets | orderBy : vm.propertyName : vm.reverse | filter : vm.search | limitTo:vm.itemsPerPage:vm.itemsPerPage*(vm.currentPage-1))">
```

And a search input

```
<input class="form-control w25 pull-right" ng-change="vm.searchChanged()" type="text" ng-model="vm.search" placeholder="Search..." />
```

And I created a fake td to get the value of filteredTickets.length (because I cannot get the value of this in the scope, if you know a way tell me)

```
 <td class="hidden" id="filteredTicketLength">{{filteredTickets.length}}</td>
```

basically the innerText of this will have the length of the tickets after the filtering.

Now here comes the problem. When I type something on the input search the totalItems does not update until I write/delete another character. Basically, the correct message is displayed after I write/delete another letter

```
    <span class="pull-left">Showing {{filteredTickets.length}} tickets of {{vm.totalItems}} found.</span>

 vm.searchChanged = function () {
        var filteredTickets = document.getElementById('filteredTicketLength');
        console.log(filteredTickets);
        if(filteredTickets !== null)
            vm.filteredTicketLength = filteredTickets.innerText;
            vm.totalItems = vm.filteredTicketLength;
    };
```

**How can I write that message showing x items of x found after the filtering? It's like the searchChanged function is being run before the filteredTicketLength is updated.**

Comment: change `ticket in filteredTickets` to `ticket in vm.filteredTickets` (bind it to scope with _controllerAs_ syntax) and use it as `vm.filteredTickets.length` inside your controller

Comment: that works but the problem is the same. the message still wrong.

Comment: searchChanged() can only be run after vm.filteredTickets changes

Comment: you can try `$scope.$watch('filteredTickets', function () {...});` instead of `ng-change` on input field

Comment: I get multiple $digest erros. I need something better